# Whole site moves left when i swipe left on a slider

Tags: css, mobile-website

https://thehollywoodtribune.com
I am working on this site and can't figure out what's causing the whole site to slide left when I swipe left on a slider on my homepage. This problem seems to exist only on my homepage and not the entire site.

Comment: Where exactly is this slider?

Comment: Right on top. It's a theme element.

Answer (score 0):

Im seeing this only happening on mobile? Maybe you can try

```
body{
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be vc_section class which is added to section in the home page
This is adding 30px width extra and adding horizontal scroll to the page. You can try removing the following css.

```css
.vc_section {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: -15px;
}
```